# Changing tab bar height (iphone - cocoa touch)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

is anyone aware of a way of adjusting the height of the tab bar on the iphone?  Is this in breach of UI guidelines?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this as it goes against the iPhone UI guidelines. The only way to achieve such a thing is to create a custom UITabBarController-equivalent class that lays out views with a custom Tab Bar.

Comment: I have done this, and it works to a degree.  I set the frame of the tabBar item.  This works, but there is still a black region behind the tabBar at the original height.  Does anyone know what this view is?

Comment: Ok, the black bar may be there because I am loading from a nib file, then adjusting the height of the tab bar.

Comment: Any luck getting this into the appstore?